# How to put dynamic layout elements in a group?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I'm trying to code a boardgame in Android. However, this game doesn't have a fixed board. Instead, the board is composed dynamically with the game tiles. So you could have different layouts depending on the position of the tiles. Here are some example of valid layouts:

Example 1:

```
1111111111111111
```

Example 2:

```
1111
1111
1111
1111
```

Example 3:

```
111111
  11
  11
111111
```

Example 4:

```
  11
111111
111111
  11
```

Let's say that the layout is stored in a txt file.

In order to make the UI, I guess that I want to create a group that acts as a container of the tiles. The code would be in charge of creating the tiles and creating layout components dynamically and putting them into the group. Also, keep in mind that position is important. In the first example, I wouldn't want the tiles to be displayed in two rows due to screen size constraints.

What is the best way of implementing this UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out a working solution. It's probably suboptimal, but it solved my question:

```
/*Start with first row*/
var currentRow = TableRow(context)
/*Go char by char*/
for (letter in boardStructure) {
    if (letter == separator) {
        /*Put row in table layout and create next row*/
        table.addView(currentRow)
        currentRow = TableRow(context)
    } else {
        /*Create element and put it in row*/
        val tv = TextView(context)
        tv.text = letter.toString()
        tv.width = 100
        tv.height = 100
        currentRow.addView(tv)
    }
}
/*Put final row in the table layout*/
table.addView(currentRow)
```

`boardStructure` is a `String` loaded from a file containing 1's and 0's as described in the question. `separator` is the character that splits each row. `table` is a predefined `TableLayout` in the layout.

Just to isolate the question I was asking, instead of putting the representation of tiles, I put 1's and 0's as received in the file to illustrate the problem. In order to continue the development from here I would check in the else-branch if `letter` is 0 or 1.